# Blogs/Websites That Showcase Windows UI Examples?

Tags: gui-design, windows-os, wpf

I'm looking for a blog or website that showcases nice UI designs. Specifically, one that has examples of Windows user interfaces. I have a few of these bookmarked (like [Beautiful Pixels](http://beautifulpixels.com/)), but they are very Apple-centric, and I have a need to divine some inspiration for a Windows application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be rather small in terms of the scope you are looking for, but I check out Little Big Details on a daily basis.  The site showcases one great usability element a day.

http://littlebigdetails.com

Answer (score 1):

I asked [something similar](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/desktop-software-design-patterns) a few days ago (for what concerns desktop software).

If you are developing on Windows platform, then you definitely should follow the [Windows UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx), which are plenty of visual examples too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this website is what you're looking for but it might give you some inspiration and examples of different design for a lots of situations. The website is Quince and the address: http://quince.infragistics.com/

Comment: The site you link to hangs like crazy with the Silverlight stuff it's trying to load.  Not a great start.

Comment: I also wonder why they chose Silverlight: from what I've seen of that website so far, regular HTML would have worked just as well (it would even have been better for many reasons).

Comment: Quince is a great resource, but I was looking for more of a showcase of full UI's rather than just particular control styles.

Answer (score 0):

One of the longest standing interaction design pattern sites around is a very useful resource.  It's not specific to Windows, but has a lot of platform agnostic principles.

http://www.welie.com/index.php

Comment: Jennifer Tidwell also wrote a few books about UI. Check her out on Amazon.